# Need to extract desired output

Tags: bash, awk

I have 100 sub-directories ending with *_t pattern where on each subdirectory , I am having this file Error.log which looks below

```
code                | error      | type      |

---                 | NTL_CON08  | Fatal     |
---                 | NTL_STR33  | Fatal     |
---                 | NTL_STR33  | Fatal     |
---                 | W_123      | Fatal     |
---                 | ER_130     | Fatal     |
```

I need the output like below where I am showing the output of one sub directory

```
acp_sub_t   
--------------------
NTL_CON08   1
NTL_STR33   2

Total Errors:   3
```

Ihave tried below code

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in *_t
do
 echo "$d"
 awk '{print $2}' Error.log | sort | uniq -c
done
```

But I am not getting the exact ouyput like above .Please help me

Comment: You don't seem to calculate the count of the errors ... or do I miss something?

Comment: @user1934428 yes , i missed the count of the errors , but my awk command itself is failing . can you please help me here

Comment: So this has nothing to do with looping over the file. Actually it is not clear at which point you are stuck. I guess you have a general idea of the algorithm of collecting a count of items in a file, and you are stuck with the implementation. You have to choose a programming language for this. You already started with `awk`, so you can stick to it, but other languages would be fine too. Now ask a new question which shows at which point in implementing your algorithm you can't proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution(EDIT):*** In case you have GNU `awk` which has `ENDFILE` then you could do this in a single `awk` itself.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  dir_name=FILENAME
  sub(/\/.*/,"",dir_name)
}
$3=="error"{ next }
NF{
  count[$3]++
}
ENDFILE{
  print dir_name ORS "--------------------"
  for(i in count){
    print i,count[i]
    sum+=count[i]
  }
  print "Total Errors: " sum
  delete count
  sum=dir_name=""
}
' *_t/error.log
```

***Proof of concept:*** When I run above get following output for test directories and test(sample) files in 2 directories.

```
1_t
--------------------
NTL_STR33 2
NTL_CON08 1
Total Errors: 3
2_t
--------------------
NTL_STR33 2
NTL_CON08 1
Total Errors: 3
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Couldn't test it since I don't have directory structure like mentioned, should work but.

Fixing OP's attempt here, fair warning using `awk` in `for` loop is usually not recommended by experts since OP has used that method so trying to fix it here.

```
for dir in *_t
do
 awk -v di="$dir" '
   $3=="error"{ next }
   NF{
     count[$3]++
   }
   END{
     print di ORS "--------------------"
     for(i in count){
       print i,count[i]
       sum+=count[i]
     }
     print "Total Errors: " sum
   }' "$dir"/error.log
done
```